# What is the rounding convention for points during character creation?

Tags: burning-wheel

According to the Contacts section:

> Contacts that hate you are half cost.

Also:

> #### Affiliated Contacts
>
> Affiliations give “free” contacts. Work-mates, partners, friends, former
>   subordinates and so on. Take the cost paid for the affiliation and divide it in
>   half.

But in a section immediately after:

> #### Affiliated Goods
>
> Lastly, an affiliation earns the character discounted goods or services—a
>   one-time resource point bonus to be spent in character generation. This
>   represents the perks afforded to the organization’s members. Divide the
>   affiliation cost by 5 (round down) for the resources point bonus.

Since it specifies 'round down' here, what was the default before? Round up? Also round down? Or potentially having a half-point?

Answer (score 3):

In the Contacts section right before Affiliated Contacts,

> Always round point costs up.

Answer (score -1):

This is Burning Wheel Classic, I presume? (2002 printing) I'd say round down as a default. That system is completely changed in Revised (2005) and Gold (2011).

Comment: Why round down, in particular? Is there some textual or other support for this?