# Does Burning Wheel have a default rounding rule?

Tags: burning-wheel

In Burning Wheel, some lifepaths get a fraction of the resources or skill points of another lifepath. Not all of the cases give an explicit rule of rounding that fraction up or down, and fractional points are of no use in the rules system.

Does the game have a default rule for rounding in a specific way, or should one simply default to the standard convention of rounding fractions to the nearest integer and halves up?

Answer (score 9):

Burning Wheel doesn't have a default rounding rule. When rounding is needed, the rounding behavior is usually specified, but alas the text is not entirely consistent.

The rounding rules provided, though, tend toward making things more difficult for the player: derived values (skills, attributes, most of the Character Burning math) round down, costs ([buying contacts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/123188)) and halved stat and skill obstacles in Fight round up.

Comment: The answer would be improved by emphasizing "No, such a role does not exist." more, and thus also that this is your extrapolation of the existing rules base. Or this is at least how I read your answer.